# APEX class to import data to custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

Before showing my code that needs debugging, I want to know if it's possible to import data exposed by a Flask API into a custom Salesforce object with an APEX class.

I know it is possible to create a web request in APEX class to execute a Flask API. Now I want to import the data exposed by the same Flask API to a custom Salesforce object with the same class that made the request. The data from the Flask API is in a csv file.

I am expecting to find the records or data I presumably imported from the CSV exposed by my Flask API in my custom object in Salesforce

I tried this code to import the data:

public class CSVImport {

```
public static void importCSVFromFlask() {

    // Here I make web request to Flask API endpoint

    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('My exposed Flask endpoint IP'); // Flask endpoint
    request.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request); // THIS PART OF CODE EXECUTES SUCCESSFULLY

    
    if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {



        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP, PERHAPS I SHOULD CHANGE CODE ENTIRELY TO:

        List<String> csvLines = response.getBody().split('\n');

        // I don't want to import 1st row of CSV file that contains headers for the fields
        if (!csvLines.isEmpty() && csvLines.size() > 1) {
            csvLines.remove(0);
        }

        // Creating records in custom object

        List<Salesforce_custom_object__c> recordsToInsert = new List<Salesforce_custom_object__c>();

        for (String csvLine : csvLines) {

            List<String> csvFields = csvLine.split(',');

            if (csvFields.size() >= 3) { // My CSV file only has 3 field

                Salesforce_custom_object__c obj = new Salesforce_custom_object__c();

                // I just want to import data from the 3rd column and 2nd row of CSV file

                obj.PriceField__c = Decimal.valueOf(csvFields[2]);
                recordsToInsert.add(obj);
            }
        }

        // Inserting records into Salesforce

        if (!recordsToInsert.isEmpty()) {
            insert recordsToInsert;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have added system debug logs on my code and it appears the 2 loops above have errors, namely:
LOOP1:

if (csvFields.size() >= 3) { // My CSV file only has 3 field

                Salesforce_custom_object__c obj = new Salesforce_custom_object__c();

                // I just want to import data from the 3rd column and 2nd row of CSV file

                obj.PriceField__c = Decimal.valueOf(csvFields[2]);
                recordsToInsert.add(obj);
            }
LOOP2:

if (!recordsToInsert.isEmpty()) {
            insert recordsToInsert;
        }

Comment: My csv file had 3 columns and 2 rows, I am attempting to import data from 2nd row and 3rd column